# How to Fix the Issue Reported in "WSO2 Carbon Context and it's usages in WSO2 Products"?

Tags: wso2

I you have read http://wso2.com/library/articles/2012/03/carbon-context-its-usages-wso2-products/, you will realize that there is a comment at the bottom explaining a use-case that fails. Please explain how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is not really a bug or limitation in the CarbonContext (at least in WSO2 AS 5.1.0, which I tried). This can be proved by using the following code snippet.

```
    try {
            CarbonContext carbonContext = CarbonContext.getCurrentContext();
            int tenantId = carbonContext.getTenantId();
            System.out.println("TENANT ID:" + tenantId);
            String username = carbonContext.getUsername();
            System.out.println("USERNAME:" + username);
            UserRealm userRealm = carbonContext.getUserRealm();
            String[] roleNames = userRealm.getUserStoreManager().getRoleNames();
            userRealm.getUserStoreManager().getRoleListOfUser(username);
            System.out.println("ALL ROLES:" + Arrays.toString(roleNames));
    } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

You will notice that the Tenant ID is properly printed, but not the Username. Though not obvious, that is because you never told the service who you are. Though you are logged into the management console, that does not mean you are logged into the services hosted on AS. If you want to enable a similar functionality, you need to setup security for the service (this can be done from the management console). For example, I used UsernameToken. Then TryIt should prompt you to enter a username and a password when invoking the service. You get the response only for valid credentials.

However, even if you do that, the code is still going to return the same exception related to the username on the CarbonContext being null. To fix this, you need to add the following two parameters to the services.xml of the respective service (ex:- conf/services.xml inside samples/HelloService).

```
    <parameter name="adminService" locked="true">true</parameter>
    <parameter name="AuthorizationAction" 
            locked="false">/permission/admin/login</parameter>
```

This will ensure that the Carbon Context is initialized with the required information about the user who logs in while invoking the service.

For this to work, you of course will have to redeploy the service with the changes to the services.xml. And, once redeployed please make it a point to check whether security is enabled or not, because redeployment removes security settings that were done using the management console.